# User control progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

Im trying to get a usercontrol to act as a progressbar. As far as i am aware, i need to draw a new bar ontop of the old one and increase its size according to the percentage completed. I have the following code, but unfortunately the green bar is at 100% even though i set the percentage property to 0% when the control is initialized. Im assuming i have made a dumb oversight but i cant see it, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

    namespace CustomPbar
    {
        public partial class Pbar : UserControl
        {
            private int PercentageValue;
            public int Percentage
            {
                get { return PercentageValue;}
                set 
                {   
                    PercentageValue = value;
                    this.Invalidate();
                }
            }


            public Pbar()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                Percentage = 0;

                    using(GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
                    {
                    path.StartFigure();

                    // top left arc 
                    path.AddArc(0, 0, (10), (10), 180, 90);
                    //rect, 180, 90);

                    // top right arc 
                    path.AddArc(((this.Width) - (10)), 0, (10), (10), 270, 90);

                    // bottom right arc 
                    path.AddArc(((this.Width) - (10)), ((this.Height) - (10)), (10), (10), 0, 90);

                    // bottom left arc
                    path.AddArc(0, ((this.Height) - (10)), (10), (10), 90, 90);

                    path.CloseFigure();

                    this.Region = new Region(path);

                    this.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlLight;
                    this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@"c:\users\FrazMan\Desktop\pb1.bmp");
                    this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                }
            }


            protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnPaint(e);

                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, ((this.Width)*((Percentage)/100)), this.Height);

                using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
                {
                    gp.StartFigure();

                    // top left arc 
                    gp.AddArc(0, 0, (10), (10), 180, 90);

                    // top right arc 
                    gp.AddArc(((rect.Width) - (10)), 0, (10), (10), 270, 90);

                    // bottom right arc 
                    gp.AddArc(((rect.Width) - (10)), ((rect.Height) - (10)), (10), (10), 0, 90);

                    // bottom left arc
                    gp.AddArc(0, ((rect.Height) - (10)), (10), (10), 90, 90);

                    gp.CloseFigure();

                    SolidBrush greenBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);

                    e.Graphics.FillPath(greenBrush, gp);

                    greenBrush.Dispose();
                }

                using(Graphics Draw = this.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    Draw.DrawString(Percentage.ToString() + "%", ProgressBar.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF((this.Width / 2) - ((Draw.MeasureString(Percentage.ToString() + "%", ProgressBar.DefaultFont)).Width / 2.0F), 
                        (this.Height / 2) - ((Draw.MeasureString(Percentage.ToString() + "%", ProgressBar.DefaultFont)).Height / 2.0F)));
                }

            }


            protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnResize(e);
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `Percentage.set` should Invalidate() the control

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hi, i changed my original code (see above) but its still not working, i just get a solid green bar, no percentage etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several places you create a `Rectangle`, but never use it. I think you want to use the `rect` width and height instead of `this` width and height.

You should also be using `e.Graphics` instead of `this.CreateGraphics()` for drawing the percentage string.

There is a large amount of duplicate code, and I recommend you keep all drawing code in `OnPaint` and when you want to redraw, call `this.Refresh()`. It will help a lot with maintenance.

Comment: @ Kendall: Im assuming i still need the code contained within the constructor though right?

Comment: You shouldn't need drawing code in the contructor. I think the control will be automatically painted on load, but if it isn't, call `this.Refresh()` in OnLoad or something.

Comment: I will give it a shot and see how it goes. The percentage is still not being displayed once i click on a different Winform, any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just saw that. I changed it as you suggested and now the background image is not stretching all the way. I didnt realise this was going to be such a challenge to get working. The percentage sign is now being displayed properly though :)

Comment: You could possibly draw the background yourself, but that almost seems like overkill, because there has to be some way to fix it. Why are you using a bitmap anyway? I would prefer graphics, but maybe you have a picture that looks good stretched. :)

Comment: i didnt know of another way of doing it. This is my first usercontrol as i found out i needed to override onpaint() to be able to display a percentage ontop of a progressbar. Unmanaged code is alittle out of reach so i took a screen shot of a blank progressbar and used that as the background image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8866/discussion-between-kendall-frey-and-hans-rudel)

Answer (score 0):

In your `OnPaint` method, you are using `Graphics.FillPath` which will fill in the entire space inside the `GraphicsPath` you are creating. Try using `Graphics.DrawPath` if you want to just draw the outline of the shape.

Comment: im trying to get a solid bar of colour. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

here is my take on custom progressbar in c#

I have % notches also, but you can get rid of them easily. works pretty good

**ProgressBarExtended.cs**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PressdMonitorSrvMod.Custom_Control
{
    public partial class ProgressBarExtended : UserControl
    {
        //constructor
        public ProgressBarExtended()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Properties

        // Create a Value property for the Progress bar
        public float Value
        {
            get { return percent; }
            set
            {
                // Maintain the Value between 0 and 100
                if (value < 0) value = 0;
                else if (value > 100) value = 100;
                percent = value;

                percentage.Text = string.Format("{0}%", value);

                //change the notch color when overdrawn
                if (value.Equals(25f))
                    notch25.BackColor = Color.White;
                else if (value.Equals(50f))
                    notch50.BackColor = Color.White;
                else if (value.Equals(75f))
                    notch75.BackColor = Color.White;
                else if (value > 0 && value < 25)
                    notch25.BackColor = notch50.BackColor = notch75.BackColor = ProgressBarColor;
                else if (value > 25 && value < 50)
                    notch50.BackColor = notch75.BackColor = ProgressBarColor;
                else if (value > 50 && value < 75)
                    notch75.BackColor = ProgressBarColor;
                //move the percentage text to the center from start
                if (percentage.Location.X < ((Width - percentage.Width)/2))
                {
                    percentage.Location = new Point((int) ((percent/100)*Width) - percentage.Width, 0);
                    percentage.Margin = new Padding(0);
                    percentage.Dock = DockStyle.None;
                    percentage.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                    percentage.AutoSize = true;
                    percentage.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
                }
                else
                {
                    //already in center, keep it in center
                    ProgressBarExtendedSizeChanged();
                }
                //redraw after changes
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        public Color ProgressBarColor { get; set; }

        public Color HighlightColor { get; set; }

        public Font LabelFont
        {
            get { return percentage.Font; }
            set { percentage.Font = value; }
        }

        public Color LabelColor
        {
            get { return percentage.ForeColor; }
            set { percentage.ForeColor = value; }
        }

        //make it readonly, hide the property
        public new BorderStyle BorderStyle;

        #endregion Properties

        #region Events

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
            // Create a brush that will draw the background of the Progress bar

            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ProgressBarColor))
                {
                using (var pen = new Pen(brush))
                    {
                    // Create a linear gradient that will be drawn over the background.
                    using (var lgBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(-1, -1, Width, Height), 
                        Color.FromArgb(150, highlightColor), 
                        Color.FromArgb(10, ProgressBarColor), 
                        LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
                        {
                        // Calculate how much has the Progress bar to be filled for "x" %
                        var width = (int)((percent / 100) * Width);
                        //draw the progress bar
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, width, Height);
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lgBrush, 0, 0, width, Height);
                        //draw the border
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        private void ProgressBarExtendedSizeChanged()
        {
            // Maintain the label in the center of the Progress bar
            percentage.Location = new Point(Width/2 - percentage.Width/2, 0);
        }

        #endregion Helper Methods
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope I never write code like that. That Value setter... *shudder*

Comment: @Mayank: That looks alot better than what ive managed to piece together. Thanks very much for sharing.

Comment: thanks, ofcourse the code can use little cleanup but it provides an basic idea how you can create something and then build on top of it.

Comment: We need the other code as well for the designer. This is a partial class definition. Does not compile!

Comment: @GMAN the XAML part is really simple, the logic was the hard to figure out. So you should be able to write the XAML for a progress-bar.